# Pictures don't appear in voyager laravel

Tags: laravel, image, path, voyager

Hello i'm working on laravel project , so in the part of admin voyager , the pictures in the folder `public/assets/img` don't appear in the tables ,
Some pictures appear and other not .
any help how to solve this problem ?

this is the filesystems.php

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
```

Comment: how do you call image in blade?

Comment: @STA the problem in the admin part , the tables don't show the pictures for exemple when i add a blog with picture the voyager just show me the url and not the image

Comment: Can you show me how do you show that images on your blade?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the line starting with url to

'url' => env('APP_URL').'/nameofmyrootfolder/storage/app/public',

This allowed the link to the images to be resolved.